# Why does inheriting from System.ComponentModel.Component prevent object from being garbage collected (at all)

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

My original question was whether or not it is important to unregister a self referenced event handler in classes inheriting from e.g. Component. They offer a Disposed event where once can deinit stuff.

But I was playing around it and realized something odd: Deriving from `System.ComponentModel.Component` does prevent the destructor from being called at all (even at the end of application.

Here is a sample that explicitly uses GC.Collect to force collection (testing only, never using this in prod code)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CSharpEventHandlerLifetime
{
    public class LongLiving : Component
    {

        public LongLiving()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating object");
            // Disposed += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
        }

        ~LongLiving()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Destructor called");
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void _create()
        {
            using (var l = new LongLiving())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Generation is {0}", GC.GetGeneration(l));
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _create();

            GC.Collect(); // this should call dtor of LongLiving


            Console.ReadKey(); // wait before end
        }
    }
}
```

When I remove the inherited Component class totally (change the `using` into plain `new`) or replace it with IDisposable (and implement some empty Dispose method) I clearly see that calling GC.Collect calls the dtor of LongLiving.

I do not understand this behaviour as I would at least expect on application exit to break into the ~dtor but it does never happen when derived from Component.

Comment: Note that Finalizable objects aren't garbage collected with a single GC. They survive until the next garbage collection.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - true, but they survive the first collection precisely because their finalizer has been scheduled. So if they survive, and they're one of very few objects waiting to be finalized, it will still be surprising that the finalizer doesn't execute (within a reasonable time scale, finalizer thread not blocked somehow, etc)

Comment: Could you elaborate "aren't garbage collected with a single GC". What is the next garbage collection if the application exist. SuppressFinalize however sounds more clear to me.

Comment: @Damien My point was just that, since you cannot guarantee when that will be.. the test is flawed.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - but the fix to the test is to insert a call to `WaitForPendingFinalizers` rather than to just immediately run a second collection, which is what your first comment implies will fix things.

Comment: @Damien Hence "note", not "heres a fix" :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Component`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx) already implements the Disposable pattern, that includes a call to [`GC.SuppressFinalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize.aspx) when complete. And `Dispose` is being called when the `using` block exits.

So the object is garbage collected, it just never has its finalizer called.

If you have any cleanup to do, you should override [`Dispose(bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9yzd5cx.aspx).

E.g. this is `Component`s `Dispose` method:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    this.Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```